# Form with variable number of criterias on Symfony4 / Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's take https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#building-the-form example form but only for Search in tasks list instead of save.

Goal is to allow searches on task, dueDate or both criterias (in my real case, I have 9 criterias)

Here are *src/Repository/ResultRepository.php* :

```
class ResultRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Result::class);
    }

    public function findMultiKeys($task, $dueDate): array
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->andWhere('d.task = :task')
            ->setParameter('task', $task)
            ->andWhere('d.dueDate = :dueDate')
            ->setParameter('dueDate', $dueDate)
            ->getQuery();

        return $qb->execute();
    }   
}
```

It require both criterias to return result(s)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a lot of searches and find:

- [How do I use a complex criteria inside a doctrine 2 entity's
  repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349790/how-do-i-use-a-complex-criteria-inside-a-doctrine-2-entitys-repository#16105183)
- [Symfony2/Doctrine QueryBuilder using
  andwhere()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874987/symfony2-doctrine-querybuilder-using-andwhere)
- [Doctrine2 doc - setParameters method](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html)

So I code a *$where_string* variable to construct my variable where.
and a *$parameters* to construct my variable parameters array, and my findMultiKeys becomes:

```
public function findMultiKeys($get_form): array
{
    $where_string = '';
    $parameters = [];
    $task = $get_form->getTask();
    if ($task !== null) {
        $where_string .= "d.task = :task";
        $parameters += array('task' => $task);
    }
    $dueDate = $get_form->getDueDate();
    if ($dueDate !== null) {
        if ($where_string !== '')
            $where_string .= " AND ";
        $where_string .= "d.dueDate = :dueDate";
        $parameters += array('dueDate' => $dueDate);
    }

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->where($where_string)
        ->setParameters($parameters)
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->execute();
}
```

It works, perhaps not the best way?
In my searches, I found, of course, to use *ElasticSearch*, perhaps to much to my simple need, or I found [PetkoparaMultiSearchBundle](https://github.com/petkopara/PetkoparaMultiSearchBundle)

Bests solutions welcomes

Answer (score 0):

I have a proposition :-)

1. You can build an task4Seach entity with your 9 criteria (without
   persistance)
2. create a form type with this "data_class"
3. use it to get your datas in your repository

> ```
> $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
>
> ...
> if ($task4Seach ->getDueDate()) {
>           $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('d.dueDate', ':dueDate'));
>           $qb->setParameter('dueDate', $task4Seach->getDueDate());
>  }
> ```

Comment: 1. what is the difference with the __Task__ entity from example https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-a-simple-form  2. https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#building-the-form , ok  3. how to solve only task, only dueDate, or both?